# Is there a walrus operator in Node.Js?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

In **Python3.8** There is new operator called `walrus` which can assign new variables inside a condition. Is there something similar to it in **Node.Js** ?

```
my_var = 5
if (result := my_var == 5):
    print(result)
```

Comment: Can you clarify on operator precedence? Is this interpreted as `(result := my_var) == 5)`? or `(result := (my_var == 5))`?

Comment: result = true after this. I think they don't understand what walrus is.

Answer (score 12):

Assign and compare as one expression. To make it work in strict mode, and avoid linter complaints, wrap it in parentheses.

```
const my_var = 5;
let result;
if ((result = my_var === 5)) {
  console.log(result);
}
```

This will log `true`.

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-cond-assign#except-parens

Comment: The parens were a great pointer; helped me arrive at the following: `(t['v'] ?? (t['v'] = [])).push(1);`

Comment: FALSE answer. 
 (result = my_var === 5) -> right

Comment: @UneconscienceUneSource you are right, my answer was wrong. I just fixed it.

Comment: This is not equivalent at all to the walrus operator because it "leaks" `result` outside the `if` in addition to force you to use `let` instead of `const` (like you would do in `for (const i in ...)`).

Answer (score 5):

There's no need for a separate operator, assignment is already an expression in Javascript:

```
"use strict";
var my_var = 5;
var result;
if (result = my_var == 5){
  console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: This won't work in strict mode, which is what anyone in their right mind will be using.

Comment: I use `strict mode` often for debugging.

Comment: @Slbox fine, but the point still stands. assignment is an expression, even in strict mode.

Comment: Considering that such an assignment is an error, that's a rather stubborn response. There's nothing wrong with your answer but that's a silly thing to start debating.

Comment: @Slbox what do you mean it's an error? It's not an error. This is a normal part of the language, it is similar to the C behavior for assignment. Try this, even in strict mode.

Comment: Your updated answer isn't an error, yes. Your original answer was an error.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
const myNumber = 2;
let newNumber;

if (newNumber = myNumber === 2) {
  console.log('this works!');
}
```

It's kind of the same, it has an assignment and a comparison in the same line.
You can obviously substitute your problem with this:

```
const my_var = 5;
let result;
if(result = my_var === 5) {
 console.log(result);
}
```

As you can see it's obligatory to have a let declaration before-hand.

Answer (score 0):

This can't work unless you're not using strict mode. It's to prevent mistakes.

[You can see this part of the document on MDN for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Converting_mistakes_into_errors)

You can do what @juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned if you don't use strict mode, which I strongly advise again. Strict mode will save you 100x more headache than it will make you.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but as I noted in my comment, even in strict mode, assignment is still an expression in javascript... nothing in that link contradicts that.